# Xamarin Forms - GestureRecognizers no longer work in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For some reason all of my GestureRecognizers stopped working today when running the iOS simulator.  They all still work in Android but nothing works in iOS at this point.

I did update a lot of my NuGet packages today which potentially could have caused an issue, but I rolled everything back and the issue still happened.  And I updated my Visual Studio today to the new version 16.5.2 which was just released yesterday.  This caused a new version of Xamarin.iOS to be pushed to the MAC that is compiling the code.  Not sure if this is causing the issue or not.

Here is a very simple example:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BtnTest_Clicked" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

    <Label TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="TESTING" />
  </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

My function BtnTest_Clicked is never called.

So updating something has caused this to stop working but I can't figure out what. Any ideas at all???

Here are my installed packages for my iOS project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Autofac">
    <Version>4.9.4</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
    <Version>12.0.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Refit">
    <Version>4.8.14</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
    <Version>1.2.0.223</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="RtspClientSharp">
    <Version>1.3.3</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms">
    <Version>1.4.0</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin">
    <Version>2019.3.1023.1</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media">
    <Version>4.0.1.5</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
    <Version>1.5.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading">
    <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms">
    <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.4.0.991864" />
  <PackageReference Include="XLabs.Forms">
    <Version>2.0.5782</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: do you have the latest XCode installed?  A new version was released this week for the new iOS udpate

Comment: I have Version 11.4 (11E146) installed.  I believe that is the newest version, right?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10162

Comment: Thanks Jason!  I looked all over and didn't find that thread.  I will just sit tight and wait for a fix.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Now this issue has been fixed , you can update Xamrin Forms to the latest version **4.5.0.617** , then it will work in iOS 13.4 .

```
<Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        IsVisible="True"
        x:Name="myframe">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

    <Label TextColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="TESTING" />
</Frame>
```

The output :

```
2020-04-22 10:01:06.226721+0800 AppFrameRenderer.iOS[37914:1276862] TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped
```